# In Java, are enum types inside a class static?

Tags: java, enums, scope

I can't seem to access instance members of the surrounding class from inside an enum, as I could from inside an inner class. Does that mean enums are static? Is there any access to the scope of the surrounding class's instance, or do I have to pass the instance into the enum's method where I need it?

```
public class Universe {
    public final int theAnswer;

    public enum Planet {
        // ...
        EARTH(...);
        // ...

        // ... constructor etc.

        public int deepThought() {
            // -> "No enclosing instance of type 'Universe' is accessible in this scope"
            return Universe.this.theAnswer;
        }
    }

    public Universe(int locallyUniversalAnswer) {
        this.theAnswer = locallyUniversalAnswer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand what you're trying to describe. can you give a small code sample perhaps?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Yes, nested enums are implicitly static.

From the [language specification section 8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> Nested enum types are implicitly
>   static. It is permissable to
>   explicitly declare a nested enum type
>   to be static.

Answer (score 51):

It wouldn't make sense to make an instance-level (non-static) inner enum class - if the enum instances were themselves tied to the outer class they'd break the enum guarantee -

e.g. if you had

```
public class Foo {
   private enum Bar {
        A, B, C;
   } 
}
```

For the enum values to properly act as constants, (psuedocode, ignoring access restrictions)

```
Bar b1 = new Foo().A
Bar b2 = new Foo().A
```

b1 and b2 would have to be the same objects.