# Switch case with enum in Android

Tags: java, android, enums

Hello I am making an application where I am trying  to define the constant using `enum` and trying to access those constants in the switch case of the `doInBackGround` method of `AsynTask` but there it saying me

LOGIN_API_CALL cannot be resolved to a variable

```
public class TeemWurkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private enum WebAPIConstants {
        LOGIN_API_CALL, FORGOT_PASSWORD_API_CALL;
    }

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private Context mContext;
    private TaskCompleteListener taskCompleteListener;
    private int method;

    public TeemWurkAsyncTask(TaskCompleteListener taskCompleteListener, int method) {
        this.taskCompleteListener = taskCompleteListener;
        this.method = method;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name));
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.please_wait));
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(mProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        switch(method) {
            case LOGIN_API_CALL:  <---- Here getting an error "LOGIN_API_CALL cannot be resolved to a variable"

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: i guess you need to check like this WebAPIConstants.LOGIN_API_CALL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not know what is `LOGIN_API_CALL` because it is enclosed in enum `WEBAPIConstants`. thats why you need to access it like this

```
case WebAPIConstants.LOGIN_API_CALL:
```

Comment: I tried that also where I am getting "Type mismatch: cannot convert from TeemWurkAsyncTask.WebAPIConstants to int"

Comment: i guess , at runtime doInBackground runs at seperate thread, thats why it is not able to find that.you need to either create object of asyntask class and then access using that object.

Comment: yes it runs at separate thread, I can not create a object of this AsyncTask. I am trying to make a constant file where I am declaring these but when I am trying to access again they are not

Comment: try access it like this. new TeemWurkAsyncTask ().LOGIN_API_CALL. reference from here .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663834/in-java-are-enum-types-inside-a-class-static

Comment: public class Constants {

 public static int LOGIN_API_CALL = 1, FORGOT_PASSWORD_API_CALL = 2;
 
 // Web API URL
 
 
}

Comment: declare variable final also mean public static final int ... and then access it like case Constants.LOGIN_API_CALL :

Comment: Oh great, issue was I just simply should have made to LOGIN_API_CALL to final and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems: `method` is an `int`, not an enum type, and you need to specify `WebAPIConstants.LOGIN_API_CALL`.

Furthermore, using a switch in this manner is nearly always the Wrong Thing to do; whenever practical, use polymorphism instead of a big switch block. In this specific case, `doInBackground` really, really doesn't belong to `TeemWurkAsyncTask`, it belongs to the task being executed, and you should either use `Runnable` or write your own similar interface that that `doInBackground` calls to.

Comment: I tried that also where I am getting "Type mismatch: cannot convert from TeemWurkAsyncTask.WebAPIConstants to int"

Comment: @Williams Did you read my answer? I already mentioned that `method` needs to be the enum type, not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare an int with a WebAPIConstants.

Try using the following code:

```
private WebAPIConstants method;
public TeemWurkAsyncTask(TaskCompleteListener taskCompleteListener, WebAPIConstants method) {
    this.taskCompleteListener = taskCompleteListener;
    this.method = method;
}
```

and use :

```
case WebAPIConstants.LOGIN_API_CALL:
```