# Is it possible to get enclosing instance from nested enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have the following class along with a nested enum:

```
public class MyClass {

    private Integer field;

    private enum SelectedValue{
        ALL {
            @Override
            public Integer getAmount() {
                return field; //Error: field cannot be resolved to a variable
            }
        };


        public abstract Integer getAmount();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get enclosing instance within the enum body?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, are enum types inside a class static?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663834/in-java-are-enum-types-inside-a-class-static)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nested enum types are implicitly static, see JLS 8.9. You cannot access a non-static field of enclosing class

Comment: Maybe you can provide some normative reference? I mean JLS or something similar...

Comment: It is JLS 8.9 Enum Types

Answer (score 3):

You can only access `field` if it is static.