# behaviour of enum values in switch statements when declared as inner classes

Tags: java, enums, constants, inner-classes

i know this is trivial question but this is totally intriguing me;

As inner classes'  (non-static) members cannot be directly accessed without instance of it even in outer class,

and while to access static constants u have to scope with outer class hai.x ;
but in the case of "use of enums switch as case constants" it seems to be other way around; **look dostuff2()**

> case RED: works but case value.RED gives error **an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant**

i know above statement says it all;i'm just curious

if we assume that compiler pads that 'value. ' to all switch constants..
why this isn't the case with normal declartion of enum as well **value v=RED**

```
    public class enumvalues
{
    public enum values
    {
        RED,GREEN,VALUE      
    }
    public class hai
    {
        static final int x=90;                    
    }
    public static class statichai
    {

    }
    public static void main(String []args)
{

}

    public  void dostuff2(values v)
    {
       //  v =RED this is illegal 

       // System.out.println(RED);  this will not compile because it cannot be accessed directly
      // System.out.println(x); this will not compile because it cannot be accessed directly



        switch(v)
        {
            case RED: //use of value.RED is strictly forbidden
            System.out.println("red");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `value.RED` or `values.RED`? (notice `s` in `values` in the latter)

Comment: enum values must normally be qualified. Only for switch cases a short notation was made available. _That's all._

Comment: That's just a rule of the Java programming language. There's no clear answer to the question "why". Because the designers of the Java language thought this was a good idea. It's already clear what type of enum you're switching on, so having `values.RED` instead of just `RED` in the `case` would only be unnecessary verbosity.

Comment: @Jesper shouldn't it be the same with value v  =RED as well ,see my question completely

Comment: Nested enums are always static, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663834/in-java-are-enum-types-inside-a-class-static

Comment: This is a valid question, no need to vote it down. It might be just a rule of the Java programming language, but that doesn't mean it makes sense to a new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it would require to create special case for enums for check.
consider another example

```
interface SomeInterface{}
enum Values implements SomeInterface {RED};
enum MoreValues implements SomeInterface {RED};

public  void dostuff2(SomeInterface value)
{
value = RED;
}
```

It is quite similar to your code to yours, and `dostuff2` is exactly same. As under hood for compiler enums are just regular classes. 
So to handle your example, you needed to add special case to handle enums.